# Adding info to an array from User Pointer in Parse - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, pointers, relational-database

I have two classes, one for tweets and one for users, in the tweets class I have a pointer column which includes the user info (like username, profile photo) of the tweeter.

I want to put the tweets in a table view using arrays, but I couldn't find a way to add the photo from the pointer which is actually in the user class and pointed in each tweet. What is the code for "`objectforkey`". I am trying the below one but get error.

The column name of the pointer is "`relUserPointer`" and the column I want to retrieve in the pointer is "`photo`"

**My code is:**

```
self.resultsNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("profileName") as! String)
                    self.resultsUserNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("userName") as! String)

self.resulltsImageFiles.append(object.["relUserPointer"].objectForKey("photo") as! PFFile)  /*I get the error here*/

self.resultsTweetArray.append(object.objectForKey("tweet") as! String)
```

**I also tried these ones**

```
self.resulltsImageFiles.append(object.relUserPointer.objectForKey("photo") as! PFFile)
self.resulltsImageFiles.append(object.objectForKey("relUserPointer")("photo") as! PFFile)
```

Comment: Is the pointer populated? Did you try: `object.objectForKey("relUserPointer").objectForKey("photo") as! PFFile)` (though you should really do it on 2 lines)

Comment: Hello, I tried this know as  self.resulltsImageFiles.append(object.objectForKey("relUserPointer")!.objectForKey("photo") as! PFFile) but it doent retrieve any info.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why it was not working, actually lots of people knows it I guess, but I am new to these staff,

after updating the pointer call as below:

object.objectForKey("relUserPointer").objectForKey("photo") as! PFFile)

it still was not retrieving any data, because in the query part you should add some code which is:  query.includeKey("relUserPointer")
Now it works. Thank you Milad by the way.